# Is there any way to schedule a process button's action on a regular screen?

Tags: acumatica

I have a process in a BLC extension that retrieves data from another API and inserts it into acumatica.  I want to run this process on a regular schedule, but I don't need an actual process screen to do it - since there wouldn't be any data or records to process until this method (that I want to automate) actually runs.

Is there a way to schedule / automate a process other than on a process screen?

Comment: Have you thought about just creating a process screen with a dummy data view in the graph, no grid on the screen, just a filter form, and then using the built in scheduler? I have never done it but I suspect it would work.

Comment: That's kinda what I tried to do, but it didn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a business event working on a schedule that will trigger an import scenario. From the import scenario, you can run any action that you need.

Comment: Can the import scenario just press a button on a screen and not have a data source or anything like that?

Comment: I would just make a dummy data source, you dont have to use it. There might be some wierd errors returned if nothing updates thru the import scenario though.

Comment: @pmfith you don't need a data source for scenarios triggered by a business event, Acumatica generates a data source record corresponding to the GI of the Business Event.